My ionizing smoke detector fell a month ago. Is it possible I've been irradiated?
My ionizing smoke detector is from Kidd, it's written it produces 0.6 microCuries in nominal conditions but a) It's expired since 2010 (I'm renting, just realised this), and b) It fell out of nowhere a month ago. Since then it has been sitting on my living room table.
If I got this right, assuming me and my family are within 1 to 5 meters of it all year long (we both work from home), I think this places our yearly radiation dose to 10-20 mSv, which I've heard was basically the threshold for safe worker conditions versus 4mSv for standard background radiation. I haven't double-checked this yet, but considering it fell and parts inside got definitely loose (I can feel and hear a big one clunk around for example), how concerning is this fall? I tell myself the absolute basic requirement is that the radiation cell shall survive a fall from a bigger height and with a loose battery, but honestly I have seen so many things I'm starting to doubt this is still safe to be around.
Second question, if my calculations are right, this is not what I'd call negligible radiation. Is this right and if it is, why would everyone be okay with this?
Edit: Update, I think the radiation rate specified might be all types combined, whereas alpha radiation of this energy wouldn't affect humans in a significant way - leaving gamma. This may be key.

It fell out of nowhere a month ago. Since then it has been sitting on my living room table  An obvious question is why you are keeping this at all, especially if you think there's a risk ?

Because I didn't know at the time - it's only when I finally got to re-installing it that I noticed all this. To be honest I didn't even know smoke detectors could have radiation sources until I saw it at the back of it.

The natural radioactivity in your body is approx. 0.2 uCi, I believe, so unless you swallowed the source in the detector whole you are probably going to be fine. The only component you have to be worried about are the 60keV gammas. Those have a penetration depth of approx. 1cm in water if we believe some of the diagrams online, so even most of those can't really get to your inner organs to cause serious cancers.

Just don't eat your smoke detector. You will be fine.

"if my calculations are right," What calculations? You have not presented any calculations. You have just asserted that you somehow think the dose is 10-20 mSv...

You may find the XKCD Radiation Dose Chart helpful. Of all the items on the chart, being near a smoke detector is closest to sleeping with someone.

Smoke detectors use an alpha emitter. As @hft notes, don’t eat it. Dispose of properly.

There is an alpha-particle emitting chip in the detector. It is very small, not very radioactive at ~37,000 Bq (an infinitesimal number of alpha particles compared to, say, eating a banana or pizza), and is contained within a tough shell that is in turn contained within a tougher case (the smoke detector case). Neither alpha nor gamma radiation sources this small could meaningfully penetrate your skin and flesh to your internal organs to cause serious cancers. Of course, the question is then raised: do you plan on removing the americium? If not, it's just a smoke detector - perfectly safe.

Since you seem uncertain about the fraction of gamma radiation, here is an RSDS: https://ehs.stanford.edu/wp-content/uploads/Am-241-RSDS.pdf

Gamma dose rate, point source at 1 ft, 1 mCi: 0.24 mrem/h

Your source is $6 \times 10^{-4}$ times this size, so the dose is $1.44 \times 10^{-4}$ mrem/h or $1.44\times 10^{-6}$ mSv/h. Your annual gamma dose, at 1 foot distance, would be $0.12$ mSv (which is way less than background).
The beta dose is zero. The alpha radiation should be 100% shielded by the detector and the air, as long as you don't eat it. The RSDS has something to say about that too:

Annual Limit on Intake: 0.8 µCi (Ingestion)

This "annual limit" would produce a whole-body dose of 50 mSv, so your sample, if consumed, would produce a dose of 37.5 mSv. That seems a bit high for an annual limit. I don't know about you, but I find americium too expensive to serve for an ordinary meal anyway.

A number of points.

Smoke detectors contain Americium-241, which emits $\alpha$ particles. These have very poor penetration power and are stopped by even minor shielding, e.g. the detector case.
If it fell down then it was attached to the ceiling before, about as
far away as it is on the table.
If it's expired that's probably because your detector is powered by a non-replaceable battery, which no longer has sufficient power. $^{241}Am$ has a half-life of more than 400 years, so it will probably outlast your house.
Even if the radioactive element is loose inside, that
does not increase the radiation outside. You should be safe as long as the is not released onto your table. In that case, if you clean the table from time to time, it will long ago have been removed.

Lastly, living without a smoke detector will put you at greater risk than a faulty detector ever can.


Second question, if my calculations are right, this is not what I'd call negligible radiation, far from it.

Your calculations are presumably wrong. But you have not shown your calculations, so we can not know for sure.

Is this right and if it is, why is everyone okay with this?

It is not right.

Edit: Update, I think the radiation rate specified might be all types combined, whereas alpha radiation of this energy wouldn't affect humans in a significant way - leaving gamma. This may be key.

No, this is not key. Smoke detectors contain a source that emits alpha particles.

The key concept you are presumably missing is that of shielding. For example, your skin will block those low energy alphas like gangbusters. This is why some of the comments indicate you should not eat your smoke detector.
You are also presumably forgetting about all the shielding around the alpha source inside the smoke detector: the plastic casing, the metal container, etc.
It is not the exterior of the smoke detector case that emits alphas; it is only the little alpha source embedded deep within the smoke detector that emits alphas. Thus, as long as you do not disassemble your smoke detector to the point of literally exposing the alpha source and then eat it, you will be fine.

Thanks for the answer. I'm not forgetting shielding, I'm assuming gamma radiation is relatively insensitive to the thin foil of the source, and the plastic cover - but I don't know how much of the radiation indicated is attributed to gamma, that's what I meant. And I also thought possible that alphas could go through plastic or even skin more than they could through the special source's enclosure, hence my concern after it dropped potentially damaging the source itself. But I'm more used to dealing with the effect of radiation on components through test data, so I can't say I have a reference.

One reason why Americium is used is because it emits very little gamma radiation.

@MisterMystère So, how then are you including the effects of shielding in your calculations of the dose you think you receive?

@MisterMystère "And I also thought possible that alphas could go through plastic or even skin more than they could through the special source's enclosure..." But why would you think this? Do you have any reason to think this?

@MisterMystère Alpha shielding doesn't need to be thick. Alpha particles are even blocked by tiny smoke particles, which is how the smoke detector works.

@hft well apparently these cells actually have walls that channel the radiation kind of like a laser does (didn't dig too much into that) so I just thought that the material used was efficient at absorbing alphas. Maybe by effect of density (metal vs plastic or skin), maybe not. Taking shielding into account is an overstatement in that I dealt with it in a qualitative way. Thanks
